# Задача Дек на яндексе контесте

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите пожалуйста с задачей на яндекс контесте. вот так удалось решить не без помощи интернета, но проверяющий хочет доработки. вот скриншот

Если перехватываю SizeError то программа не работает.  А по поводу распаковки не пойму как сделать(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задание:

> Гоша реализовал структуру данных Дек, максимальный размер которого определяется заданным числом. Методы `push_back(x)`, `push_front(x)`, `pop_back()`, `pop_front()` работали корректно. Но, если в деке было много элементов, программа работала очень долго. Дело в том, что не все операции выполнялись за O(1). Помогите Гоше! Напишите эффективную реализацию.
>
> **Внимание: при реализации используйте кольцевой буфер.**
>
> **Формат ввода**
>
> В первой строке записано количество команд n — целое число, не превосходящее 100000. Во второй строке записано число m — максимальный размер дека. Он не превосходит 50000. В следующих n строках записана одна из команд:
>
> - `push_back(value)` – добавить элемент в конец дека. Если в деке уже находится максимальное число элементов, вывести «error».
> - `push_front(value)` – добавить элемент в начало дека. Если в деке уже находится максимальное число элементов, вывести «error».
> - `pop_front()` – вывести первый элемент дека и удалить его. Если дек был пуст, то вывести «error».
> - `pop_back()` – вывести последний элемент дека и удалить его. Если дек был пуст, то вывести «error».
>
> `Value` — целое число, по модулю не превосходящее 1000.
>
> **Формат вывода**
>
> Выведите результат выполнения каждой команды на отдельной строке. Для успешных запросов `push_back(x)` и `push_front(x)` ничего выводить не надо.

Вот сам код:

```
def SizeError(Exception):
    pass
 
 
class Deque:
    def __init__(self, max_size: int) -> None:
        self.__max_size: int = max_size
        self.__queue: list = [None] * max_size
        self.__head: int = 0
        self.__tail: int = 0
        self.__size_of: int = 0
 
    def push_back(self, value: str) -> None:
        if self.__size_of == self.__max_size:
            raise SizeError
        else:
            if self.__queue[self.__tail]:
                self.__tail = (self.__tail + 1) % self.__max_size
            self.__queue[self.__tail] = value
            self.__size_of += 1
 
    def pop_back(self) -> None:
        if self.__size_of == 0:
            raise SizeError
        else:
            x = self.__queue[self.__tail]
            self.__queue[self.__tail] = None
            if self.__size_of > 1:
                self.__tail = (self.__tail - 1) % self.__max_size
            self.__size_of -= 1
            print(x)
 
    def pop_front(self) -> None:
        if self.__size_of == 0:
            raise SizeError
        else:
            x = self.__queue[self.__head]
            self.__queue[self.__head] = None
            if self.__size_of > 1:
                self.__head = (self.__head + 1) % self.__max_size
            self.__size_of -= 1
            print(x)
 
    def push_front(self, value: str) -> None:
        if self.__size_of == self.__max_size:
            raise SizeError
        else:
            if self.__queue[self.__head]:
                self.__head = (self.__head - 1) % self.__max_size
            self.__queue[self.__head] = value
            self.__size_of += 1
 
 
def main() -> None:
    n: int = int(input())
    max_size: int = int(input())
    queue: Deque = Deque(max_size)
    for i in range(n):
        values: list = input().split()
        try:
            getattr(queue, values.pop(0))(*values)
        except Exception:
            print('error')
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Нужно не новое исключение создавать, а отлавливать те исключения, которые могут возникать. Например может быть исключение при вызове getattr при несуществующем атрибуте, другое исключение - при вызове pop от пустого списка, третье - при вызове атрибута как метода, при том что он не является callable.

Comment: Про распаковку: `command, *arguments = *values` - в command попадет название команды, в arguments - все остальное

Comment: @insolor, Вам не составит труда, как правильно будет это сделать у меня не выходит, а сегодня нужно сдать(

Comment: Напишите помог ответ или нет, и если помог, вы можете отметить его принятым - для этого поставьте галку слева от ответа.

Comment: inslor спасибо Вам большое, распаковка очень помогла, исключения не стала перехватывать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По поводу распаковки. Вот так в `command` попадет название команды, в `arguments` - все остальное.

```
values: list = input().split()
command, *arguments = values
```

Далее по поводу исключений. Ожидаемые исключения - это конкретные исключения, которые в этом блоке try-except могут возникнуть. Т.е. это конкретные классы исключений, вместо общего класса `Exception`.

Сначала убираете ваш try-except вообще или делаете печать исключения:

```
def main() -> None:
    n: int = int(input())
    max_size: int = int(input())
    queue: Deque = Deque(max_size)
    for i in range(n):
        values: list = input().split()
        command, *arguments = values
        getattr(queue, command)(*arguments)
```

Пробуете разными способами сломать вашу программу, записываете все возникающие исключения. Например, пробуете вводить несуществующую команду, недостаточное количество аргументов, лишние аргументы, и т.д., потом добавляете `except` на соответствующие случаи.

Потом возвращаете try-except обратно, добавляете except на каждый тип исключения с выводом конкретной ошибки.

```
def main() -> None:
    n: int = int(input())
    max_size: int = int(input())
    queue: Deque = Deque(max_size)
    for i in range(n):
        values: list = input().split()
        command, *arguments = values
        try:
            getattr(queue, command)(*arguments)
        except SizeError:
            print("Ошибка размера Deque")
        except AttributeError:
            # Введено имя, которое не является именем метода класса Deque
            print("Неизвестная команда")
        except TypeError:
            # Ошибка возникает, например, если введено больше или меньше параметров чем нужно,
            # или например при попытке вызвать метод __init__
            print("Неправильный формат команды")
        ... # Аналогично обрабатываете другие ошибки
```

В конце можно добавить `except Exception:`, но обязательно с выводом фактической ошибки с полным стектрейсом (например, через [`traceback.print_exception()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exception), чтобы вы могли понять, какая именно проблема произошла), а не просто с выводом "error".